How to load local fonts in sveltekit?
trying to use these fonts in sveltekit but not working, other fonts seem to be working, it should work I tested them using in nextjs app by loading with localFont(nextjs specific) so this fonts are not broken,
Tried to define font family in css file, like so:
@font-face {
    font-family: 'P1';
    src: url('/fonts/quran/pages/p1.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

tried it by defining in tailwind config and in inline style also style="font-family: P1;", didn't work
Tried loading with js like below which also didn't work though I see the font is being added to document.fonts and setting font-family to the target element:
export const loadQuranPageFont = async (pageNumber: number) => {
    const fontName = `quran-page-${pageNumber}`;
    const fontUrl = `/fonts/quran/pages/p${pageNumber}.woff2`; // 'fonts' is located in the static folder, also tried to put inside 'src/lib' folder and call it like '$lib/fonts/..' either didn't make difference

    const fontFace = new FontFace(fontName, `url(${fontUrl})`);

    try {
        // Load and add the font
        const loadedFont = await fontFace.load();
        document.fonts.add(loadedFont);

        // Set the CSS variable for use
        const element = document.getElementById('quran');
        element.style.fontFamily = fontName;
        console.log(`Font for page ${pageNumber} loaded and set to CSS variable.`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("[Couldn't load font]: ", err);
    }
};


Your code is looking for the font from the drive root folder, could you share your folder structure? If your CSS file is in the same folder as the font, then just change url('/fonts/quran/pages/p1.woff2') to url('./fonts/quran/pages/p1.woff2')

/ paths are ambiguous to Vite/will not be included as assets in the build output.
Use a relative path import or import from $lib.
@font-face {
  /* Navigate using ./ or ../ paths. */
  src: url('../../lib/quran/pages/p1.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  /* $lib points to src/lib directory */
  src: url('$lib/quran/pages/p1.woff2') format('woff2');
}

